# Which is the best way to pass data component to component in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have seen there are many ways to pass data component to component in vue js but I want to know which is the best way from listed below

1) Vuex

```
store.commit('anyMethod');
```

2) $root : With emit an event useing $root

```
this.$root.$emit("eventName",data)
```

3) Server Bus : Where we have to create and a new Vue instance and then we can pass data on entire app

```
Vue.prototype.$serverBus = new Vue(); 

and we can use like 

this.$serverBus.$emit('logged-in');
```

Anyone help me to find out the best way?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It entirely depends on the _context_ of what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Lewis:

> It entirely depends on the context of what you're doing.

In the long/big run, I would advice to use Vuex.

Speaking from experience, Vuex and it's guide's way of structuring it makes Vuex really manageable in bigger *(and smaller)* projects.

Since Vuex has this [well documented structure](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), it makes it really easy for new developers accessing your source to understand your code since it is so well known in the community.

**"ServerBus"(EventBus)** on the other hand is more used on smaller and less advanced applications.

**this.$root** seems more like a hack for me and I would strongly advise against this. It is a feature that has arise due to Vue's flexibility. -Even the official docs kinda backs this: [Handeling edge cases](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Root-Instance)